# LinkedIn developer profile API

Tags: linkedin-api

In LinkedIn developer profile API, after I integrated the API with our system, using OAuth 2.0 auth, I couldn't find a way to retrieve authenticated user detailed data like user skills, projects, education, location
I tried to use the r_liteprofile scope, data that was retrieved was only firstName, lastName
I didn't find any helpful information in the documentation can help,
I need to get more detailed data from the user (The user already knows what permission he is approved for, so why does LinkedIn limit this! )

#linkedin

Answer (score 0):

To access the fields you're interested in (courses and other information not available using the `r_liteprofile` and `r_basicprofile`) you need to join the LinkedIn Partner Program.

[Here are all the fields you can access ONLY by joining it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile) - it's basically everything other than profile picture, email, public URL, and basic personal info.

**You can apply to become a Partner by using [this link](https://developer.linkedin.com/content/developer/global/en_us/index/partner-programs/apply).**